# MVC ReportViewer Not loading for huge reports

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportviewerformvc

I am using ASPX report viewer control in my MVC application and its working fine in normal cases.
In some cases while i am trying to load a report that took some time load (query execution  for the report's dataset is taking more than 3 minutes ) and the report viewer itself is not loading in to the MVC web portal

While checking the network console i can see an error like below

```
 ReportViewerWebForm.aspx net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200
```

Any known reason for this error and any way to resolve this timeout kind of error

Comment: An update for this issue here. It is because of the difference in parameters . From web portal we passed certain parameters which is not associated with design of the report

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing **executionTimeout** through `web.config`, which sets the allowed execution time for the request:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <httpRuntime
    maxRequestLength="1048576"
    executionTimeout="3600" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8), that property indicates the maximum number of seconds a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET.  (Defaut is 110 seconds)

Comment: The current settings is   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="600" /> <!--600 seconds-->